# Replace many "+++" for one "+"

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I have

```
$string="this+++is+test";
```

Need with `str_replace` change many "pluses" for one "plus";

example: `this+is+test`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solution assumes you don't have `"+"`s at the ends of your string. Since you don't in your example, I assume that's OK.

```
php > $string="this+++is+test";
php > echo implode('+', # reassemble the string on a single '+' sign
        array_filter( # strip empty-string parts of the array entirely
          explode('+', $string) # Split the string into array on '+'
        )
      );
this+is+test
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace` for this time.

```
$string="this+++is+test";
$string = preg_replace("/[+]+/", "+", $string);
```

Here `[+]+` means the `+` sign to be `1` or more time consecutively.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex

```
\++
```

The above regex matches `+` any time.

And replace it with

```
+
```

And since we are replacing it with `+`, there is no probs.

Comment: The anonymous downvoter is the scourge of StackOverflow.

Comment: +1 for the regex. your regex is correct. not sure why its down voted!! may be they didn't understand this? or wanted further explanation??

Comment: Probably because it's replacing single "+" with "+" unnecessarily. I didn't downvote, but I like Jonny 5's solution better.

Answer (score 1):

Replace 2 or more `+` with `+`:

```
$str = "this+++is+test";

$str = preg_replace('/\+{2,}/', "+", $str);
```